# msmtp: sendmail: account default not found: no configuration file available (system wide configuration)

Tags: 20.04, email, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to setup Ubuntu 20.04 with msmtp as a system configuration.

I installed msmtp (v1.8.6-1) and heirloom-mailx (v12.5-2+deb7u1build0.14.04.1).

Config file **/etc/msmtprc** (chmod: 600) has the following:

```
# Set default values for all accounts.
account default
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile        /var/log/msmtp

# gmail
host           smtp.gmail.com
port           587
from           <account>@gmail.com
user           <account>
password       <password>

# Syslog logging with facility LOG_MAIL instead of the default LOG_USER
syslog LOG_MAIL
```

Log file **/var/log/msmtp** file mode is 660.

File **/etc/mailrc** (chmod: 600) contains the following:

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
```

When I try to use sendmail to send an email from terminal I get the following *sendmail: account default not found: no configuration file available*.

The same error comes up if I directly invoke msmtp.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Warning 1** : My advise is based on Debian `msmtp` package.
**Warning 2** : Newer `msmtp` packages no longer install msmtp as set group id for security reasons.

**Recommended Fix**: Make `/etc/msmtprc` owned by group `msmtp`.

```
chown root:msmtp /etc/msmtprc
chmod 640 /etc/msmtprc
```

---

**Explanation:**  `msmtp` binary is installed as set group (`msmtp`) id

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/msmtp
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root msmtp 139000 Aug 20 16:24 /usr/bin/msmtp
```

Comment: This works on Raspbian buster as well!

Comment: chown: invalid group: ‘root:msmtp’

Comment: Check explanation. 1) Is /usr/bin/msmtp installed as set **group** id? 2) Is it owned by group other than msmtp?  **ANYWAY**: It seem to work on **some** version of distributions.  If it does not work for your name distribution version you use and provide version of msmtp pacjage you installed.

Comment: Since bookworm, the corrent permission is 600 instead of 640.